# Python deleting from text specific type of words

Tags: python, text

I would like to delete from whatsapp chat.txt file all the dates, username and emoticon.
The file looks like this :

```
10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user1: example chat
10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user2: 
10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user3: example chat
10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user1: example chat
10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user2: 
10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user3: example chat
```

It is possible to write a script in python that recognizes the username and dates deleting it. Leaving only the chat text?
I immagine i should use regex expression and maybe convert all the text to a string.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to build a regexp for that. Emoji regexp taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404752/removing-emojis-from-a-string-in-python)

```
import re

str_in = """10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user1: example chat 
            10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user2:   
            10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user3: example chat  
            10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user1: example chat  
            10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user2:   
            10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user3: example chat"""

dates_filtered = re.sub(r'(\d+\/\d+\/\d+, \d+:\d+ [AP]M - [ \d\w]+: )', '', str_in)

regrex_pattern = re.compile(pattern = "["
        u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
        u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
        u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
        u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
                           "]+", flags = re.UNICODE)
emoji_filtered = regrex_pattern.sub(r'',dates_filtered)


blank_lines_filtered = re.sub(r'(\n\s*\n)', '\n', emoji_filtered)

print(str_in)
print('---------')
print(dates_filtered)
print('---------')
print(emoji_filtered)
print('---------')
print(blank_lines_filtered)
```

prints

```
10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user1: example chat 
10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user2: 
10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user3: example chat 
10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user1: example chat 
10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user2:  
10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user3: example chat
---------
example chat 

example chat 
example chat 
 
example chat
---------
example chat
              
example chat
example chat 

example chat
--------- 
example chat
example chat
example chat 
example chat
---------
```

Comment: This one works pretty well except the fact that sometimes user names are more then one word. For example: 
10/4/19, 7:18 PM - Arnold Pence: 
10/4/19, 7:18 PM - Mike: example chat 
10/4/19, 7:18 PM - Mariah: 
10/4/19, 7:18 PM - David sons: example chat.                                                                     
                                                                                                                                             
How to match all the cases?

Comment: fixed by changing `[\d\w]+` to `[ \d\w]+`

Answer (score 0):

Similar question about regex and Whatsapp logs with python

[Regex to match whatsapp chat log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280191/regex-to-match-whatsapp-chat-log)

Code from the first answer

```
^
(?P<datetime>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}[^-]+)\s+-\s+
(?P<name>[^:]+):\s+
(?P<message>[\s\S]+?)
(?=^\d{2}|\Z)
```

Answer (score 0):

A super simple way here would be to iterate line by line and split on `:`. If we can assume that the `date, time - username: message` will always follow this format, we can grab everything after the second `:`

```
text = '''10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user1: example chat
10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user2: 
10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user3: example chat
10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user1: example chat
10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user2: 
10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user3: example chat'''

for message in text.split('\n'):
    print(message.split(':')[2:][0])
```

Outputs

```
 example chat
 
 example chat
 example chat
 
 example chat
```

Comment: with list comprehension : `[message.split(':')[2:][0].strip() for message in text.split('\n')]`

Comment: @user_na As stated in the answer, if the format continues as the pattern shows in the example this will work. I find it highly unlikely that the original pattern `date, time - username: message` will change in the file.

Comment: It also crops messages with `\n` inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use list comprehension:

```
print([ message.split(':')[2:][0] for message in text.split('\n') ])
```

Comment: this does not remove emojis

Answer (score 0):

here

`sentence='10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user1: example chat 10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user2:  10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user3: example chat 10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user1: example chat 10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user2:  10/4/19, 7:18 PM - user3: example chat'

chat=re.findall('-\suser\d:\s([a-zA-Z\d]|.*?) \d', sentence)

print(chat)`

output:

```
['example chat', '', 'example chat', 'example chat', '']
```

Comment: suggest improvement for catching last chat